# How to calculate time spent below a threshold?

Tags: r

I have a plot with time as a `PosixCt` object on the `x-axis` and a dependent variable **"ODBA"** on the `y-axis`. The experiment was a `600-second` trial. How do I calculate the total time in seconds that `ODBA` was below a certain threshold `(e.g. 0.25)`?

Comment: If @akrun's answer doesn't do it for you, please make this question reproducible by including sample data (either literal `data.frame(...)` or an unambiguous sample with `dput(head(x))` ... note that frames with `POSIXt` objects are notoriously not-easy to just copy/paste from here into an R session).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sum`

```
sum(as.numeric(format(time, "%S"))[ODBA > 0.25])
```